# For projective algebraic varieties V and W and a holomorphic map V to W, why is the canonical map from V to its graph a morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm trying to a understand a proof from Milne's excellent online notes on algebraic geometry (https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG510.pdf). Here is the statement of the result and the proof:

COROLLARY 15.6. Any holomorphic map from one projective algebraic variety to a second projective algebraic variety is algebraic.

PROOF. Let $\varphi:V\rightarrow W$ be the map. Then the graph $\Gamma_\varphi$ of $\varphi$ is a closed subset of $V\times W$, and hence is algebraic according to the theorem. Since $\varphi$ is the composite of the isomorphism $V\rightarrow\Gamma_\varphi$ with the projection $\Gamma_\varphi\rightarrow W$, and both are algebraic, $\varphi$ itself is algebraic.

I have two questions about the proof:

(1) The theorem Milne references in the proof is 'any closed analytic submanifold of $\mathbb{P}^n$ is algebraic' and so when he says 'Then the graph $\Gamma_\varphi$ of $\varphi$ is a closed subset of $V\times W$, and hence is algebraic according to the theorem', this relies on the fact that $\Gamma_\varphi$ is also an analytic submanifold   of $\mathbb{P}^n$, which comes from the fact that $\varphi$ is holomorphic, and not simply because $\Gamma_\varphi$ is closed? I think this is correct but it seems odd that he chose to say 'closed subset' rather than `closed analytic submanifold of $\mathbb{P}^n$'.

(2) Why is the map $V\rightarrow\Gamma_\varphi$ algebraic? It makes intuitive sense that it would be but how do we actually show this? I assume there's something obvious that I'm missing since this part of the proof was glossed over.

Answer (score 2):

(1) The proof should say "closed analytic".
(2) Actually, this is a tricky question if you don't assume that the varieties are nonsingular (or at least normal), as in the proof of 15.5. Then you can use 8.60 in the current version of the notes to see that the projection from the graph to $V$ is an isomorphism, which means that the map back is algebraic.  See the discussion in 8.61.

Comment: One of the composites is the identity, which is of course algebraic, but the second composite is $f$ itself, which is what we are trying to show is algebraic. So I'm not quite sure how we can use this argument. Do you think you could clarify?

Comment: Do you know of an elementary proof using only the definition of regular map in the smooth case?